# Date auto conversion

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a sheet with name "02-05-2015".
I use

```
Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
MsgBox (sheetname)
```

It displays 02-05-2015 in msg box.
But if I use

```
Range("K2").Value = sheetname
```

Its shows 05-02-2015. If cell format is changed as dd/mmm/yyyy, It shows 05-Feb-2015. Why this problem occurs. I don't know.
Even if I use

```
Range("K2").Value = Format(sheetname,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

No change occurs.
I need 05/02/2015 or 05-02-2015 in cell as date format.

Comment: In order to describe your situation accurately, it would be helpful to know whether your computer uses *mm/dd/yyyy* or *dd/mm/yyyy* in it's system regional settings. The example you've provided is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This is behaviour-by-design. When you put any value into a cell Excel tries its best to figure out what to do with it. This includes making a number an actual number (not always desired in the case of something like a DUNS number or part number with leading zeroes) and trying to reconcile what appears to be a date into the system's regional settings of either *mm/dd/yyyy* or *dd/mm/yyyy*. The trouble with *02-05-2015* is that it could be either *05-Feb-2015* or *02-May-2015*. The decision for either **DMY** or **MDY** is made on the computer's system regional setting (found in the Control Panel).

From your description, it would appear that you wish Range("K2") to hold a date representing *02-May-2015*, not *05-Feb-2015*. It also seems that your system is set to a default of *mm/dd/yyyy*.

This three step routine should get you the results you are looking for.

```
With Range("K2")
    .Value = Chr(39) & .Parent.Name
    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("K2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 4)
    .NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
End With
```

That takes the worksheet name and stuffs it into K2 by forcing it as a text value with a prefacing single quote (e.g. `'` or *tick*). It then uses the Text-to-Columns command to interpret that as a **DMY** date and store it as a date in the current system regional settings. Finally, it applies some cell formatting to get the desired cell display value.